# dracena plant leaf develop yellow streaks and rough surface

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

Hello recently my dracena plant has been developing yellow streaks on upper leafs and the surface of these leafs feels rough with white spots that look like blisters

[image]

[image: The large leaf is the most affected]

not sure what this is exactly any help appreciate it

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link describes all the [dracaena](https://mrec.ifas.ufl.edu/Foliage/folnotes/dracaena.htm) family members and notes their sensitivity to fluoride in soil with a Ph of less than 6. When I was doing interior landscaping I saw this a lot in older plants of the Janet Craig or similar demerensis cultivars.  This was in an area where the tap water is alkaline and fluoridated.

My theory is that the Ph of the water is not as important as the quantity of water and light received and the amount of organic matter in the soil.

Most indoor plants are over watered and only receive a fraction of the light they could use.  When the plant is new the organic matter will help buffer any fluoride and help maintain a good air/water ratio in the roots.  As it is consumed by the roots the soil compacts and holds less air.  Fungus/virus/bacteria can now take advantage of these conditions to grow in the soil.  Then they move into the plant and create the bumps you see in the leaves.

If I am right your indicators are:

- only happens on older leaves
- plant has not been repotted recently

To resolve:

- move to better light
- repot
- reduce water and increase drainage (do not let sit in water)

Comment: thank you. Will these bumps go away? Not sure how old it is but its been with me for about4 months. I also have worms in the soil(most likely from me adding backyard soil to the pot soil). would they help reduce fungus/bacteria/viruses?

Comment: iv add another image showing the whole plant. the largest leaf is the most affected

Comment: @questv  So that is an older leaf and consistent with an opportunistic virus/fungus/bacteria.  Most plants can outgrow this if light is increased and water is decreased